# center pixel of a group neighbored of pixels in a sparse image

Tags: matlab

I want to do in matlab the following: I have a sparse image that have some values representing an elliptic region. I want to find the center pixel of these valued pixels. I can't use any ellipse or circle equation in that as the region is not regular, but all pixels are adjacent.

Comment: Please post an example image to make your question more concrete. You should try to use `regionprops`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...this function was quite sufficient for the task.